# Javascript split checking with null

Tags: javascript, string

i have a problem with split() function in JavaScript,

i have percent value it coming from server and maybe null maybe string

and if it number have prefix '-' i need to show exactly what i fetch from server, but if this string have just number i need to add '+' prefix, i found one solution but problem in null example:

```
const percent = '25%' // But maybe 'null' maybe '-25%' 

const prefix = percent !== null ? percent.split('')[0] === '-' ? '' : '+' : ''
console.log(prefix + percent)
```

My code doesn't work, where is mistake?

Comment: And you're sure you somehow are getting the actual value `null` from the server, and not a string

Comment: Not related to your question, but you can use indices with strings too. Thus, instead of `foo.split("")[0]`, just do `foo[0]`.

Answer (score 4):

The `'null'` is different from `null`

```js
const percent = 'null' // But maybe 'null' maybe '-25%' 

const prefix = (percent !== null && percent !== 'null') ? 
  percent.split('')[0] === '-' ? '' : '+' 
  : '';
console.log(prefix + percent)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You are using constant variable and  "Constants are block-scoped, much like variables defined using the let statement. The value of a constant cannot change through re-assignment, and it can't be redeclared." and also split is string operation. 


 var percent = '' // But maybe 'null' maybe '-25%'
    var prefix = percent !== null ? percent.split('')? '-' : '+' : ''
    console.log(prefix + percent)
```